# SQL:Count of values in one column in relation to another column

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
id      date      time_stamp  licenseid   storeid    deviceid    value
1     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0add      52
2     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0add      54
3     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0add      53
4     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0001       1         0add      54
5     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0002       1         0add      59
6     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0003       1         0add      62
7     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0004       1         0add      55
8     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0bdd      53
9     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0bdd      52
10    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0bdd      52
```

I need the count of deviceid based on the number of timestamps it is seen in. So the output would be something like: 0add is seen in 2 timestamps hence the count is 2 whereas 0bdd is seen in one time stamp hence 0bdd has count of 1. The number of licenses corresponding to the device per time stamp is not considered for the count.

```
date        deviceid count
2015-06-12   0add     2
2015-06-12   0bdd     1
```

I am trying with this query below but unable to verify if it works as the query has been executing for quite some time now and not showing any result :

```
select date, deviceid, count(deviceid) from my_table group by deviceid, time_stamp
```

Please note that the number of rows I am running this query on is 2,000,000

1. Is the above query right for my output
2. If so how can I optimize it to run fast for my table size

EDIT: The column labeled `time_stamp` is a `TIME` type.

Comment: Your group by should be on `date`, not `timestamp` based on the statement... "I need the count of deviceid based on the number of timestamps it is seen in. " and I think you want `count(Distinct TimeStamp)` since licenseID would cause the count to be higher than desired and deviceID oesn't represent the unique count you're after.  However even this can be problematic as timestamp is a much more granular level than what is displayed, you'd have to format timestamp to a HH:MM:SS to truncate off the nano-secods

Comment: Also, MySQL has DateTime objects that are used for storing both a date and time in one column, so you eliminate the need for two separate ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to consider a couple of things here:

- If you want the number of timestamps per device for each date, you should be grouping by device and date, not device and timestamp.
- You have rows where a device id has the same date and timestamp, so you may want to consider looking for distinct timestamps in each date.

The fix to the first one is self explanatory, and for the second one you can change your aggregation to `COUNT(DISTINCT timestamp)`. Try this query:

```
SELECT device_id, date, COUNT(DISTINCT timestamp) AS numRows
FROM myTable
GROUP BY device_id, date;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/766ce/1) example using your sample data. It is also worth noting that putting an index on the device_id and date columns may help this query run faster, if this query is still slow for you. See the comments for more discussion on this.

Comment: You might suggest some indexes to answer his second question, and that would make this answer complete.

Comment: Close, but I think this will not result in correct count since timestamp is more granular than what is displayed... you'd need to truncate off the less than second amounts befor the distinct would work correctly.  Assuming timstamp is really a "timestamp"

Comment: @xQbert, why are you assuming there is a less-than-second component to the timestamp?   It could be a varchar.

Comment: @xQbert assuming it is a time/timestamp rather than some arbitrary varchar field

Comment: Agreed if it is truly a HH:MM:SS with no fractional seconds then this works.  but timestamp as column name gives me me pause.  still give the answer a +1

Comment: @TabAlleman I'll be honest, I'm not sure what indexes should be added to make this more efficient. Any suggestions? Also, do you think the reason the query is running so slow is because it was grouping by the wrong field?

Comment: I put it as a `TIME` column in my fiddle example, but that is up for speculation. I went with the data that was displayed, not what it was labeled as.

Comment: The two columns in the GROUP BY would suffice for the query as shown.  If any other columns are used as filters in the "real" query, then they should be included as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman That's what I thought, too, but it doesn't look like they can put an index on device_id and date, because it's not a unique pairing.

Comment: Indexes don't have to be on unique pairings.   Primary Keys do, but indexes can be non-unique.

Comment: @xQbert et al  the timestamp column is actually labeled as time_stamp. I had a typo and is of the type 'time'

Comment: Lucky guess, my fiddle doesn't have to be changed! :D

Comment: @fheo then mcAdam331's answer here should work for you right?

Comment: @xQbert On the face of it yes. I am still testing it. Will accept it once verified.

Comment: @McAdam331 Took around 50s to execute but gave the right results. I will try indexing the columns and see if it improves.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, deviceid, count(deviceid) from my_table group by date,deviceid
```

You had timestamp instead of date. The query really should have not returned anything as it was an invalid group by.